# NLTK count frequency of sub phrase

Tags: python, nltk

For this sentence: "I see a tall tree outside. A man is under the tall tree"

How do I count the frequency of `tall tree`? I can get use a bigram in collocation, such as

```
bgs= nltk.bigrams(tokens)
fdist1= nltk.FreqDist(bgs)
pairs = fdist1.most_common(500)
```

but all I need is to count a specific sub phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@uday1889's answer has some flaws:

```
>>> string = "I see a tall tree outside. A man is under the tall tree"
>>> string.count("tall tree")
2
>>> string = "The see a stall tree outside. A man is under the tall trees"
>>> string.count("tall tree")
2
>>> string = "I would like to install treehouses at my yard"
>>> string.count("tall tree")
1
```

A cheap hack would be to pad in the space in the `str.count()`:

```
>>> string = "I would like to install treehouses at my yard"
>>> string.count("tall tree")
1
>>> string.count(" tall tree ")
0
>>> string = "The see a stall tree outside. A man is under the tall trees"
>>> string.count(" tall tree ")
0
>>> string = "I see a tall tree outside. A man is under the tall tree"
>>> string.count(" tall tree ")
1
```

But as you see there's some problems when the substring is at the start or end of a sentence or next to a punctuation.

```
>>> from nltk.util import ngrams
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> string = "I see a tall tree outside. A man is under the tall tree"
>>> len([i for i in ngrams(word_tokenize(string),n=2) if i==('tall', 'tree')])
2
>>> string = "I would like to install treehouses at my yard"
>>> len([i for i in ngrams(word_tokenize(string),n=2) if i==('tall', 'tree')])
0
```

Answer (score 1):

The count() method should do it:

```
string = "I see a tall tree outside. A man is under the tall tree"
string.count("tall tree")
```